# PHP Permutations with exception of similar sequence

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, permutation

My permutation/combinations of data

```
$combinations = [[]];
$data = [

        ['alteration1', 'alteration2', 'alteration3', 'alteration4' ... upto 5 each],
        ['alteration1', 'alteration5', 'alteration6', 'alteration7' ... upto 5 each],
        ['alteration8', 'alteration9', 'alteration10', 'alteration5' ... upto 5 each],
        ... upto 6 max
    ];

    $length = count($data);

    for ($count = 0; $count < $length; $count++) {
        $tmp = [];
        foreach ($combinations as $v1) {
            foreach ($data[$count] as $v2)
                $tmp[] = array_merge($v1, [$v2]);

        }
        $combinations = $tmp;
    }

  print_r($combinations);
```

The script would generate such sets

```
 0 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "alteration1"
    1 => "alteration1"
    2 => "alteration8"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    0 => "alteration1"
    1 => "alteration1"
    2 => "alteration9"
  ]
```

... the issue begins when I start getting the same sequences of data in my case array index 0 and 20 would be exactly the same despite any position.

```
 20 => array:3 [▼
        0 => "alteration8"
        1 => "alteration1"
        2 => "alteration1"
      ]
      21 => array:3 [▼
        0 => "alteration1"
        1 => "alteration9"
        2 => "alteration1"
      ]
 $final = []; // remove duplicates
```

The basic idea is to keep $combinations array's unique (alteration1,alteration2,alteration3) is equal to (alteration3,alteration1,alteration2) therfore it should be skipped in the $final array. I haven't really found anything around SO and google. Thanks for the help. $data dimentions [ from 1 - 6 ], each array inside can be [ 1 - 6 ]. Following script might not be working as expected .

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ad5084386c2185f7619aaac152b638873039ee8

Comment: What could be possible duplicates?

Comment: (alteration1,alteration2,alteration3) is equal to (alteration3,alteration1,alteration2) f.e any same combination that repeats, ABC = BCA = CBA to simplify should check upto 6 elements ( and return only 1 ) position doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We iterate over the data and find unique elements first for each set using [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).
- We then [natsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) them to get a sorted form and serialize them using [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). By doing this, we would get the same serialized code for sets `ABC`,`CBA`,`BAC` etc.
- We then find duplicates using keys check inside a variable, say `$set`. If the serialized key is set, we exclude it from the results, else we include it in our final results.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$data = [
    ['alteration1', 'alteration4',],
    ['alteration2','alteration3'],
    ['alteration2','alteration3'],
    []
];


$combinations = [[]];

foreach($data as $index => $current_data){
   $current_data = array_unique($current_data);   
   if(empty($current_data)) continue; 
   $temp_combinations = [];
   foreach($current_data as $value){
       foreach($combinations as $each_combination){
           $temp_combinations[] = array_merge($each_combination,[$value]);
       }
   }

   $combinations = $temp_combinations;

}

$set = [];
$unique_combinations = [];

foreach($combinations as $each_combination){
    natsort($each_combination);
    $serialized_form = implode(",",$each_combination);
    if(isset($set[$serialized_form])) continue;
    if(empty($each_combination)) continue;
    $unique_combinations[] = $each_combination;
    $set[$serialized_form] = true;
}

print_r($unique_combinations);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/Do6oH

Comment: what if an array is empty, that might also be a case, else its working

Comment: @KavvsonEmpcraft wait, there's a bug. I am fixing.

Comment: @KavvsonEmpcraft I have updated my answer. I have also added a test data set in the code where it prints the combination of `1,2,3` only once and so goes with others. Initially, it was giving `1,3,2` also along with `1,2,3`.

Comment: @KavvsonEmpcraft  Added a check for empty data as well.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/F8NNH consider that line 7, that's what I meant

Comment: @KavvsonEmpcraft Fixed that. I thought the data was symmetric in nature.